# How to set JDialog position according to the parent JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

I am having one parent frame in my system and one dialog that I need to show on Click. But I need to show that dialog in the middle of the parent frame. All time. And that parent frame position may not be the same all the time. So how to set it all time in to the middle?

I am Working on Swing `JFrame`.

```
com.verve.visdashboard.NewOkCancelDialog cancelDialog = new com.verve.visdashboard.NewOkCancelDialog(new FrameOwnserPnael(), true);
cancelDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(new FrameOwnserPnael());
cancelDialog.setLocationByPlatform(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`setLocationRelativeTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo%28java.awt.Component%29) method for your `JDialog`.

```
JDialog d = new JDialog();
d.setLocationRelativeTo(COMPONENT);
```

here `COMPONENT` is parent frame.

Comment: M trying it but its not happening bcoz i have used like this. look i have update Question..

Comment: Try to remove `cancelDialog.setLocationByPlatform(true);`

Comment: its same when move parent frame and clicked then position is no giving in center.

Comment: In that case try to post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with reproducing problem, because that should work.

Comment: ya u Right that i should report for that.

Answer (score 1):

The basic code should be:

```
JDialog dialog = new CustomDialog(...);
dialog.pack();
dialog.setLocationRelativeTo( parentFrame );
```

The size of the dialog is (0, 0) until you use the pack() method so the dialog can't be centered properly.

Comment: let me try i will try and let u know okey.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you create a new parent frame. Instead you should create your parent frame only once and use that object to pass it as parameter.

```
FrameOwnserPnael parentFrame = new FrameOwnserPnael();
com.verve.visdashboard.NewOkCancelDialog cancelDialog = new com.verve.visdashboard.NewOkCancelDialog(parentFrame, true);
cancelDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(parentFrame);
cancelDialog.setLocationByPlatform(true);
```

Comment: But when i change the Position of the parent Frame then the position of the Dialog is not changing. :(

Comment: Each time before you show the dialog, you need to call setLocationRelativeTo method to set the location of dialog.

Comment: ya i got but i put one button on the event threw which the dialog is been called all time but if we change panel location and then if we clicked on button its not showing relative position.

Comment: My answer is wrong... See comment by alex2410